# How do I get a makefile to compile multiple sources?

Tags: c, makefile

I would like my makefile to compile two sources, osmprun.c and echoall.c.
Currently it's just compiling osmprun.c, which creates errors.

Im at my wits end, Im not experienced with makefiles at all and I just don't understand what im doing wrong.

My makefile is:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wconversion -g 
LIBS=-lm -lpthread
DEPS=

BUILD_DIR := build

SRCS := osmprun.c echoall.c
OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


echoall: $(OBJS)
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $< $(LIBS) -o $@

osmprun: $(OBJS)
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $< $(LIBS) -o $@



.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o *~ core

test:
    ./osmprun
```

Can somebody help me figure out my mistake and explain what the problem is?

EDIT:

I've now changed the part where it is supposed to compile the two files to:

```
echoall: echoall.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

osmprun: osmprun.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```

But it is still only compiling echoall, not osmprun

Comment: Don't do `mkdir` in multiple recipes.   Make the directory in a different rule and add a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

It would help greatly if you included the command you typed and the output you got, and what you wanted to get, especially because your terminology is not quite accurate.  It's not true that make is not compiling all the object files.  The problem is at the link stage.

However, I don't understand what your makefile is intended to do.  You have two targets and they both depend on the SAME set of object files:

```
echoall: $(OBJS)

osmprun: $(OBJS)
```

Do you need to link both of those object files together?  If so then what is the difference between the `echoall` program and the `osmprun` program, if they both contain the same set of object files?

Or, do you want to create the `echoall` program from the `echoall.c` source file and the `osmprun` program from the `osmprun.c` source file?  If so, why do you list both objects as a prerequisite for both programs?

In any event your problem is here:

```
echoall: $(OBJS)
        mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $< $(LIBS) -o $@

osmprun: $(OBJS)
        mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $< $(LIBS) -o $@
```

(the `mkdir` here are useless: you know that the directory already exists because you already built the object files, but they don't hurt anything).

The problem is you're using `$<` which is the *first* prerequisite.  Because both prerequisite lists are the same, you're building both programs from the same, single source file.

If you want both programs to contain both object files, you should use `$^` here not `$<`.  If you want each program to contain only its related object file, you should change the prerequisites to contain only the object file it should be built from (and also use `$^`).

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice and edited the file, but it is still only compiling the top one of the source files and then stopping

Comment: make always only builds the first target in the file by default.  If you want to build a different target you can ask for it on the command line, like `make foo` to build `foo`.  If you want the default behavior to be to build multiple files, then you can make the first target in the makefile something that lists all the files you want by default as prerequisites; for example you can add `all: echoall osmprun` as the first target in the makefile.  You might want to add `.PHONY: all` in that case to let make know that `all` doesn't represent a real file, it's just an internal target.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to do, thank you so much! You're a lifesaver